# Creating a 2 column table from multiple columns with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort through a set of survey results where respondents selected one location as their home, and potentially many locations for where they conduct their research.

Residence.    Research locations

Alabama,      The Bahamas, CA, KY

California,   AL, Peru

Etc, for 98 rows.

I would like to create a table with source and destination columns that I can then use in ArcGIS to create a radial flow line map. What I need from VBA is to take the above table of multiple rows and a varied number of destination columns, and arrange it in a 2 column table that duplicates the residence field for each destination.

Residence.    Research location

Alabama,      The Bahamas

Alabama,      CA

Alabama,      KY

California,   AL

California,   Peru

From here I can add xy coordinates for each residence (source) and research location (destination) to create my radial flow line map.

I've looked at a few examples of range to single column code, but I haven't found anything that also relates to my source column. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your sheet will look something like this:

[image]

And output will be as:

[image]

Following code will accomplish this task:

```
Sub Data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate

    While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        n = 1
        Label = ActiveCell.Value
        While Selection.Offset(0, n) <> ""
            Item = Selection.Offset(0, n)
            Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = Label
            Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = Item
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            n = n + 1
        Wend
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked like a charm and saved me a lot of tedious work!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Best of luck for your project.